# openpyxl: Seeing "valueerror cannot convert to excel" when using worksheet.append(ListVariable)

Tags: python, openpyxl

I’m also seeing the error message “ValueError cannot convert to Excel.” 
I’ve looked at this site and it seems many others have gotten similar error messages but my code doesn’t look the same and the solutions are not clear to me.

The exact and complete error message reported is:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert ['NHL Teams.zip',
'https://canvas.uw.edu/courses/1675266/files/folder/Lesson 05', 
'https://canvas.uw.edu/courses/1675266/files/105188746/download?wrap=1', 'NHL', '', 'BOS.png', '', 
'Unsupported file type: (.png) skipped in search.'] to Excel
```

I’m working on a program that loops over some data and saves the result to an Excel file that the program creates.  I’ve been adding rows to the Excel file using the construction similar to:

```
WorkbookObject.append(list_of_strings_variable)
```

This works, However in some cases I need to call a function that returns a list of (list of strings) and add the strings from the inner list to the end of an existing list and save the results as new rows in the spreadsheet.

To test my logic and the syntax I need, I wrote this small test program which models the data transformation I’m intending and it does save the contents to the spreadsheet.

Here is my test program:

```py
import openpyxl

EXCEL_COL_NAMES = ['File Name',
                   'Path in Canvas',
                   'Download Link',
                   'Keywords found in Filename',
                   'Keywords found File Conents',
                   'Zipfile Member Name',
                   'Keword in Zip Member Name',
                   'Keword in Zip Member Contents']

def someFunction(n):
    result = []
    
    for i in range(n) :
        result .append(['sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth'])
    return result

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.append(EXCEL_COL_NAMES)

testData = someFunction(20)

for item in testData:
    ws.append(['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth' ] + item)

wb.save('Test.xlsx')
```

Here’s the contents the Excel file generated by the test program:

Contents of Test.xlsx generated by python code above:

[image]

But when I include this logic in the larger program I’m writing, the program crashes and reports the `"ValueError cannot convert"` message.

Here is a fragment from the larger program:

```py
elif (file_extension == '.zip'):
    kw_in_content =  zipSearch(downloaded_file_path, KEYWORDS_LIST, ZIP_FOLDER)
else:
    kw_in_content = f'Unsupported file type: ({file_extension}) skipped in search.'
            
print(f'Keywords in File Content: {kw_in_content }')
       

"""
Now I'm ready to write the results of the search to the Excel file.
            
For most file types I'm writing one row per file and the last three fields, 
which contain data about zip files, are unpopulated.  For zip files I'm 
writing one row for each file inside the zip file, including data in the 
columns specific to zip files.
        
"""

if not file_extension == '.zip':
    results_list = [file.display_name, Files_section_url, file_download_url, kw_in_filename, kw_in_content, '', '', '']
else:
    for zipfile_member in kw_in_content:
        results_list.append([file.display_name, Files_section_url, file_download_url, kw_in_filename, '', ] + zipfile_member)
                
        # These two print statements are for debugging only.
        print(f'Type of list literal = ', type([file.display_name, Files_section_url, file_download_url, kw_in_filename, '', ] + zipfile_member))
                print(f'zipfile_member = {zipfile_member} (type = {type(zipfile_member)}, results_list = {results_list}')

        ws.append(results_list)
        wb.save(EXCEL_FOLDER + '/' + EXCEL_FILENAME)
```

Here is some sample data returned from my function "zipSearch" that is creating a list of (list of strings):

```
[['BOS.png', '', 'Unsupported file type: (.png) skipped in search.'], 
['CHI.png', '', 'Unsupported file type: (.png) skipped in search.'], 
['DAL.png', '', 'Unsupported file type: (.png) skipped in search.'], 
['DET.png', '', 'Unsupported file type: (.png) skipped in search.'], 
['NJD.png', '', 'Unsupported file type: (.png) skipped in search.'], 
['SJS.png', '', 'Unsupported file type: (.png) skipped in search.'], 
['TBL.png', '', 'Unsupported file type: (.png) skipped in search.']]
```

All the data going into the Excel file is of type string.  I’ve double and triple checked that the lists I’m sending to Excel always have the same number of strings.  I’m not clear why openpyxl would have trouble writing some lists to Excel and not others.

1. I was expecting my data to be written to the Excel file.
2. I'm not sure what else I should try.  The smaller sample program models the data transformation I wanted and caused no trouble for the openpyxl module. The logic and syntax I'm using in the larger program should be identical from the perspective of the openpyxl module.
3. I don't think it should matter, from the perspective of the openpyxl module, how many values are in the list I'm passing to Excel.  But I checked that anyway.
4. I did add some print statements to examine the data going into this logic, everything seemed in order there.

Comment: The error sounds like you have a list in a list like your example code and `sample data returned from my function "zipSearch"` I.e. the list for append should be `['a',  'b', 'c']` not `[['a',  'b', 'c']]` or in other words `ws.append(['a',  'b', 'c'])` . See the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=append). If you have a list of lists then loop them and if you have two or more lists for the same row then combine them

Comment: @moken.   Thanks so much for catching my logic error!  I should have seen that.   Yes, I had always intended to pass a list and not a list of lists to ws.append().  

Thanks for taking the time to read and reply to my posting.